# sql search using like not working

Tags: php, mysql, forms

i have an search box on website but whenever we search, it doesn't give any output.

I want to search for page title from database. But don't know what is wrong.

```
<div id="siteSearch">
    <h3>Site Search</h3>
    <?php
    if (isset($_POST['search'])) {
        $search = $_POST['search'];
        $query  = "SELECT * FROM pages WHERE ptitle LIKE '%$search%'";
        $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
        $count = mysql_num_rows($result);
        if ($count > 0) {
            while ($fetch = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                echo $fetch['ptitle'];
            }
        }
    } else {
        echo "No result found!";
    }
    ?>
</div>
```

Comment: text inputs have a "placeholder" attribute that's useful to give the user an hint about what it's needed and will spare you the need to write all that javascript to clean it...

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: I don't got any output. If i run the sql query on phpmyadmin then it works fine and give output.

Comment: So it echo's `No result found!`?

Comment: Infact i don't got the else condition,

        else
        {
            echo "No result found!";
        }

Comment: I don't understand. Do you or don't you see 'No results found!'?

Comment: No i don't see echo's output [No result found!?]

Comment: do you have any errors in your PHP error log?

Comment: @James No there is no error.

Comment: ok so you've narrowed it down. no errors, and not echoing "No result found" which means it's hitting the `$count>0` == TRUE. just under the `$count>0`echo in there "here" if you get that on screen, move it to inside the while. this is a useful debugging method as it shows you where in your script PHP is actually getting to. ie if it echoes it in the while and it's not echoing results, you know where to look. If it doesn't echo just under `$count>0` then it's not getting results (you also need an else clause on your num_row count too)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the semicolon after the while loop:

```
while($fetch = mysql_fetch_array($result));
```

Please remove the semicolon in this line.

Comment: done, [ while($fetch = mysql_fetch_array($result)) ]. Working!

Answer (score 0):

You have a misplaced closing bracket. The one above `else` should be 5 lines below. As it currently stands, the `else` clause relates to `if (isset($_POST['search']))`.

Comment: i don't know but every one is flag my question "This question is not useful", rather than giving answer. Its really very frustrating!

Comment: @Rohan I suppose this is mainly because you have not tried (or failed to demonstrate that you tried) debugging your code. Please read this [FAQ]. In particular: "Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question? Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and above all, it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!"

Comment: sir i have already try alot of searching at stackoverflow but don't got anything related to my query that's why i share my code along with the question. I also try with pre tag and echo my query but don't got any result in the output. That's why need your support.

Comment: @Rohan Fine, you should add these debugging steps to the body of your question: **Sharing your research helps everyone**, even if you did not succeed, at least it allows ruling out the obvious.